# How can I view my offline/local HTML file on iPad?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, files-app

in iOS (iPad) in the files app, I want to view a HTML file, I don’t want to open it and see the code, I want to see it as the end user: When i click on the html file, it shows a preview (an empty page) since this step is not calling any links (js, css, etc) I tried to tap and hold to see if I can open it with safari but I can not chose safari.
I tried to open it in dropbox also. Again it shows a empty page.
goodreader app: it opens the file but freezes and the app stops responding after.
I also didn’t find a way from safari to locate a specific file and open it.

But I know that iOS is able to easily display HTML files, because when I use the Pyto3 App on iPad (Python IDE for iPad and iPhone) and create a plot with plotly and then execute `fig.show()` then safari opens automatically and shows it exactly as it would in OS/Windows in a browser.

I really can not believe that there is no way to tell iOS to open a HTML file with safari.

Is there a way directly with safari? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edge Browser App worked.

I some how assumed that the Edge Browser App will not do more than the Chrome Browser App (since Edge is based on Chromium). But i was wrong. From all i tried (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Goodreader and many more), Edge was the only thing that worked.

Go to file, chose open with different App, chose more, chose Edge, wait for quiet a bit, and it shows.

Update:
sometimes "PDF Expert" also worked.

Comment: Worked perfectly today for an `ibom.html`. What a pain, but glorious to have a solution!